# Subgroups and well-defined bijection

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with subgroups $H$ and $K$. Show that $f: H/(H\cap K) \rightarrow HK/K$ by $h(H ∩ K) \mapsto hK$ is a well-defined bijection.

I am really confused about the bijection stuff. Well-defined seems obvious, but cannot write it out rigorously, basically to show $f(h'(H \cap K))=h'K$ right? ($f$ is the bijective function)

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $K$ is normal in some larger group $G$ containing $H$ and $K$, which by the way you are implicitly assuming in the question. The group $HK$ is the group generated by all products of elements of $H$ and $K$. Given $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ by normality we have that $kh=hk^{\prime}$ for some $k^{\prime }\in K$ this shows that any element of $HK/K$ is of the form $hK$.

The map

$$H\rightarrow HK/K$$
given by
$$h\mapsto hK$$ is surjective by the above remark.

The kernel of this map is clearly $H\cap K$, this shows then that $H\cap K \lhd H$ and that the map
$$H/H\cap K\rightarrow HK/K$$
is a well defined isomorphism.

Comment: Nice answer. I think this is the best way to prove this fact (that is, giving the surjective map and then applying the first isomorphism theorem). +1

Comment: K does not have to be normal

Comment: $K$ does not have to be normal in $G$, but you must have stronger assumptions than you are giving. You need conditions to guarantee that $HK$ is a subgroup, and $K$ is a normal subgroup of $HK$. Otherwise, your question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Note that what you have claimed is not strictly true unless $H \leq N_{G}(K)$. You've been given the map, which makes your task a lot easier. Here are some hints:

1) You must show that $f$ is injective, i.e. that if $f(h_{1}(H\cap K)) = f(h_{2}(H\cap K))$, then $h_{1}(H\cap K) = h_{2}(H\cap K)$. Note that $h_{1}K = h_{2}K$ implies $h_{1}^{-1}h_{2} \in K$. But $H$ is a subgroup, so $h_{1}^{-1}h_{2} \in H$. Hence...

2) You must also show that $f$ is surjective, i.e. that for each $hK \in HK/K$, there exists a coset in $H/(H\cap K)$ whose image is $hK$ under $f$. This is pretty straightforward, so I leave this to you.

3) Showing that $f$ is well defined amounts to showing that the image is independent of the coset representative. That is, if $h_{1}(H\cap K) = h_{2}(H\cap K)$, then $f(h_{1}(H\cap K)) = f(h_{2}(H\cap K))$ (note that this is NOT the same as injectivity!) But this is not too hard to see. If $h_{1}(H\cap K) = h_{2}(H \cap K)$, then $h_{1}^{-1}h_{2} \in H \cap K$, so $h_{1}^{-1}h_{2} \in K$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think normality of $K$ must be assumed, try to give a proof of part 2) of your outline.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: normality of $K$ is a little strong. You only need that $K \leq N_{G}(H)$ (after all, this question amounts to the second isomorphism theorem). But I agree that I have not made this clear. I'll edit the post. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Correction: the above comment should read: "You only need that $H \leq N_{G}(K)$" for the way this question is written.